# Runtime of optimized Primehunter

Tags: java, big-o

Ok so I need some serious runtime help here!

This method should take in an int value, check its primality, and return `true` if the number is indeed a prime. I understand why the loop only needs to go up to `i` squared, I understand that the worst case scenario is the case in which either the number is prime (or a multiple of a prime). But I don't understand how to quantify the actual runtime.

I have done the loop myself by hand to try to understand the pattern or correlation of the number (`n`) and how many loops occur, but I literally feel like I keep falling into the same trap every time. I need a new way of thinking about this!

I have a hint:

> "Think about the SIZE of the integer"

which makes me want to quantify the literal number of integers in a number in relation to how many iterations it does in the for loop (`floor log(n)) +1`). BUT IT'S NOT WORKIIIING?! I KNOW it isn't square root `n`, obviously.

I'm asking for Big O notation.

```
public class PrimeHunter 
{

    public static boolean isPrime(int n)
    {
        boolean answer = (n > 1) ? true : false; //runtime = linear runtime

        for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) //runtime = ?????
        {   
            if (n % i == 0) //doesn't occur if it is a prime
            {
                answer = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        return answer; //runtime = linear runtime
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?  The Big-O notation of this algorithm?

Comment: Why exactly are you asking here when the answer is easily findable using Google?

Comment: *"I KNOW it isn't square root n, obviously."*  Why do you say that?

Comment: A professor TOLD ME it was NOT the obvious answer (after I showed him my work for square root n) otherwise that was my first answer. that it would be in big O of square root n

Comment: do you have to figure out the big o for this algorithm or do you have to develop one that's better than sqrt(n) ?

Comment: I just need to know the big O / runtime of THIS algorithm

Comment: Check the edited-part in bottom of my answer. I'm not sure how to express it, but I think I got it.

Comment: but is this the worst-case runtime? In worst case, the break would never happen because it would reduce the time

Comment: The worst case runtime is for prime numbers, correct?

Comment: I think so? prime numbers and squares of primes since the squares of primes will actually loop until square root of n (the bound)

Comment: I have no idea. I would double check with your professor on this. Also, `boolean answer=(n>1);` is adequate and is equivalent to `boolean answer=(n>1)?true:false;`

Comment: I hope you can run with the hint if I mention to examine the line with `%`. It seems to me this will indeed work out to `O(sqrt(n))`

Comment: This question would better belong on the Computer Science site https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`I KNOW it isnt square root n obviously.`

Well, if it isn't square root, there's absolutely no other possibilities.

I thought about this, and unless you omitted something here, it absolutely has to be related to square root. If I'm mistaken, correct me.

For the loop to be log(n), you would have to do Math.pow(10,i) in your for loop.

The runtime, in your case, would be O(sqrt(n)-1).

To compare `n` to `i`, you must take the square root of n but since `i` starts at 2, you must subtract 1 from it.

EDIT:
Actually, you are right.

the aforementioned O time is only true for prime numbers.
For non-primes, it is the smallest prime positive factor of n minus 2.

If you remove the `break`, it will make calculating the runtime a lot easier.

Comment: I've been ignoring the break entirely because, in worst case runtime, the break will never happen. I mean, if I include non-primes when im trying to find a function it REALLY messes things up. square root n really is NOT working. I wouldn't be asking if it wasnt obviously not working like this. when plotted, the graph (if anything) looks logarithmic NOT at all like square root n

Comment: Plug in 961748941, and it will run 31011 times. It is not logarithmic.

Comment: unless it has a really dramatic coefficient(?)

Comment: Java ints only go up to 2 billion or so. Actually, I think I may have found an exception: if you cast a long to int, for example 9617489411234l will become 1057635490 in int form because longs take up more bytes. Perhaps that's it.

Answer (score 0):

A visual way of doing this is to make a graph.

Choose a bunch of `n` values, say, 1 through 20.  Plot out a chart where the x axis is the `n` value, and the y axis is the worst case number of times the loop will run.  You should get a visualization.

Once you have a visualization, it should become more apparent.  If not, then you can plot some known Big-O notations on this same graph and see how they compare.  Eg, is it close to a linear value (`O(n)`), an exponential value (`O(n^2)`), or a logarithmic (`O(log(n))`) value?  If you need a more exact Big-O value, you can go from there.

A second way to think about it is to focus on this bit:

```
I understand why the loop only needs to go up to i squared
```

Think about it in terms of `i`, not `i*i`.  The for loop goes until `i*i = n`, where `i` is the number of iterations.  Solve for `i`.

Comment: ok so I did make a graph but it really doesnt have a clear resemblance to any generic functions like the ones you mentioned, not square root n either. It does resemble the function mentioned in my hint though (it has steps)

Comment: Can you post your data table (n, i values) in your question?  If nothing popped out at you, the you might have calculated your values incorrectly.

Comment: (2,0) (3,0) (5,1) (7,1) (11,2) (13,2) (17,3) (19,3) (23,3) (29,4) (31,4) (37,5) (41,5) (43,5) (47,5) (53,6) (59,6) (61,7) (67,7) (73,7) (79,7) (83,8) (89,8) (97,8) (101,9) (103,9) (107,9) (113,9)....

Comment: I havent been plotting i values, just quantity of iterations. which is related to i values but I mean, the real concern for runtime is the amount of iterations right? the function of amount of loops in terms of n(input)

Comment: You're plotting only the prime numbers.  Plot the run time for the numbers 1-20.  The Big-O notation isn't based on just the primes -- it's based on all input.  Finding that a number isn't prime takes CPU, too.

Comment: Quantity (count) of iterations is what we want (I never mentioned plotting `i` values).  I think, though, you still might be missing the point.  The upper limit of `i` (the value of `i` that causes the loop to exit) is the number of iterations.  In any case, it'll help if you create a table for n=1...20 and figure out the iteration for each value of n.

Comment: but it ends up just looking like a line with values that spike up to higher values (the primes) because every other digit is divisible by 2 (thus making most of these values an execution of 1)

Comment: Ok, so you have a graph, and you notice that you don't get a perfect line because some numbers are prime, and some fail the optimization.  You're on the right track.  1:  What might that line resemble if it were perfect (if it didn't have the spikes/dips), and 2:  what would that line look like if you removed the `if (n % i == 0)` check?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5jwvkq430s Ok so when I remove the break it looks a LOT like a logarithmic function... ._. I mean, maybe linear but the iterations repeat more as values get bigger

Comment: And when you eliminate even numbers, you eliminate about half of the iterations that would happen by short-circuiting them.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one loop. It executes `maxi - 2 + 1` times where `maxi*maxi = n`. And the operations inside are the same (take (are bounded by) a constant amount of time). I think you were overthinking this.

Actually there could be a little stumbling block which your prof might be getting at. The time complexity of modulo operation, `%`. In that case the inner term is not quite constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) <----------- Runtime of floor(logn) +1

      boolean answer = (n > 1) ? true : false; <------ constant runtime

      for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) <------runtime square root n


Total runtime = log(sqrtn) + 1

reduces to 10^n

F.M.L.

QED
```